# Postgraphile cannot query SQL function

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

I have a SQL function that I am unable to query with Postgraphile. I am getting `Cannot query field \"get_eligible_shifts\" on type \"Query\"."` I noticed that in the PostGraphiQL the function does not appear. Why would I not be able to query on my SQL function?

`Postgraphile query`

```
{
  get_eligible_shifts(
    args: {workerId: 1}
  ) {
    id
    start
    end_time
    profession
    worker_name
    facility_id
    facility_name
    worker_document_id
    facility_requirement_id
  }
}
```

`errror`

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"get_eligible_shifts\" on type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_eligible_shifts` needs to be included as a query in your *schema*. For example:

```
type Query {
  get_eligible_shifts(args: ArgsInputType): [Shifts]

   ... more query definitions
}
```

Only once a query has been included in the schema can you *resolve* it using a resolver, in your case the SQL function you allude to.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Graphile custom queries documentation](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-queries/):
Custom queries must be marked as STABLE (or IMMUTABLE, though that tends to be less common)

After that my query appears in the GraphiQL explorer as expected!

Thanks to [Graphile help forum](https://discord.com/channels/489127045289476126/1149090431678824598/1149093110756954234)